# Getting bug while archive ios build

Tags: xcode, react-native

Here is error massage
**File /Users/abdulhaseeb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Noonan-bwjmuumqnljyoecvidmrjuoafhkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Noonan/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Noonan.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with React Native, please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues**

how to solve it ....

Comment: *This must be a bug with React Native, please report it*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.